# Size value with Storyboard and Auto-layout

Tags: xcode, storyboard, autolayout

Using Storyboard with Auto-layout, I noticed something: I added a UIScrollView and connected it with an IBOutlet. In my UIViewController, if I make a log:

```
NSLog(@"size %f",self.myScrollView.frame.size.width);
```

the result is 0, but visually the measurements are correct.

If I turn off Auto-layout, the log parameters are correct, and visually everything remains unchanged.

How do I see the correct values ​​with auto-layout?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can view the correct size values by asking for them in `viewDidAppear`, because in `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` they haven't still been determined using autolayout:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  NSLog(@"size %f",self.myScrollView.frame.size.width);
}
```

As Shown Here:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%s size %f",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,_holderView.frame.size.width);
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   NSLog(@"%s size %f",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,_holderView.frame.size.width);
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
   NSLog(@"%s size %f",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,_holderView.frame.size.width);
}
```

> 2013-04-17 12:02:05.442 TryALASB[5421:c07] -[FirstViewController
>   viewDidLoad] **size 0.000000** 2013-04-17 12:02:05.444 TryALASB[5421:c07]
>   -[FirstViewController viewWillAppear:] **size 0.000000** 2013-04-17 12:02:05.457 TryALASB[5421:c07] -[FirstViewController viewDidAppear:]
>   **size 150.000000**